# How to get summary graph of custom (subclass) Keras layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How do you print a summary() of the layers of a custom layer?

model.summary() prints a beautiful summary graph of the entire model, but the subclass layer called 'magic_layer' here, which has many layers within it, is aggregated...

```
Model: "transformer"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
positioning (PositionalEncod (None, 504, 6)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
magic_layer (CustomLayer)    (None, 6, 504)            3088040   
_________________________________________________________________
g_pooling (GlobalAveragePool (None, 504)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 504)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 32)                16160     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 165       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,104,365
Trainable params: 3,104,365
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

If you have a custom-defined Tensorflow/Keras layer (read more about that here: [Making new layers and models via subclassing](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/) - Francis Chollet) then the summary call won't break out all the layers in that sublayer. 'magic_layer' in this example, is the subclass layer that I'm interested in.

How could you get this same print-out of sublayers for the layer called 'magic_layer' in this example?

`model.layers[1].summary()` does not work unfortunately... Perhaps I need to include a summary def in the custom layer class, but I was hoping there was a way of inheriting this functionality from the model class.

Answer (score 1):

Since a model is a subclass of layer, just make your custom layer subclass from tf.keras.Model instead of tf.keras.layers.Layer. Now you can print a summary of your "layer" via summary().

model.summary is not recursive - it will not print a summary of embedded models. If you want that, you'll have to write it yourself, or just create your own summary function based on the original source.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07a22914c8114a74238fd86741749cab5af299ce/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L116

Comment: I didn't know that models were a subclass of layer. Would've thought it was the other way around. However, I originally did make my custom layer subclass from keras.layers.layer
```class EncoderLayer(keras.layers.Layer):``` and I made the model from ```tf.keras.Model``` as you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, my dyslexia caught up to me and I reversed layer and model. Revised! Subclass from tf.keras.Model instead of Layer.